# IBM MobileFirst - Encryption algorithm for encryptWebResources

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

What encryption algorithm and logic is used by the IBM MF framework to encrypt web resources when "encryptWebResources" attribute in "Security" element is set to true (in descriptor file)?
What is the strength of the encryption?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should expect this information to be provided to you... generally speaking it uses OpenSSL.

Comment: Thanks Idan. What could be the reason for not providing this information? Ours is a financial sector client who need to be assured about the strength of encryption. Do you think PMR should be the right way to get this information?

Comment: Yes. PMR would be more appropriate.